# Getting the Actual and Maximum Hard-disk Usage of a VM

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

Is there any way to get the actual hard-disk usage of a VM using Powershell? When I use the **TotalDiskAllocation** it does give me the maximum hard-disk that was assigned to the VM but not the actual size that it is using.

```
Measure-VM -Name * | select-object -property VMName, TotalDiskAllocation
```

Also, is it possible to integrate that new script to the script above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I am unable to integrate the *actual* and *maximum* disk usage into one script so I separated them into two.

For the actual disk usage, I used the following script:

```
Get-VM -VMName * | Select-Object VMid | Get-VHD | Select-Object Path, Size, FileSize
```

For the maximum allocated memory, I used the following script:

```
Measure-VM -Name * | select-object -property VMName, TotalDiskAllocation
```